# Fastest way to find a document in mongodb without using _id field

Tags: database, mongodb, coding-efficiency

Here is a sample document which I'm going to use.

```
{
    "_id"       : ObjectId("5cc6ccec131355bb173c64ba"),
    "username"  : "user1",
    "firstname" : "john",
    "lastname"  : "doe"
}
```

I need to find documents using the `username` field everytime.

I used `hashed index` but, it does not allow to make it a `unique` field.

```
{
    "ok"       : 0,
    "errmsg"   : "Currently hashed indexes cannot guarantee uniqueness. Use a regular index.",
    "code"     : 16764,
    "codeName" : "Location16764"
}
```

If there are about 1M of items, what is the fastest method to find the item by `username` field?

Comment: any reason behind going for hashed index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Create a unique index. I don't anticipate any performance issues even with 1M records. I get decent performance even with collections > 1 billion in size in a 5 member replica set.

```
db.members.createIndex( { "username": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Option 2:
Store the username into the _id field, since you know it is unique. You will lose the ability to use _id field to detect when a record was created, so you'll need to store another field with the timestamp if you need that ability.